# How to fix "Illegal method name <init>$" error in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I followed all advices on http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/doc/helpInfo/jsoRestrictions.html and still get the infamous `<init>$` error.

The following statement triggers the error:

```
final OpenCTM ctm = OpenCTM.create();
```

Where OpenCTM is:

```
public final class OpenCTM extends GObject {

    protected OpenCTM() {}

    public static native OpenCTM create() /*-{
        return new $wnd.GLGE.OpenCTM();
    }-*/;

    public native void setSrc(String url, String relativeTo) /*-{
        this.setSrc(url, relativeTo);
    }-*/;

}
```

The whole code is located in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/neothemachine/glge-gwt) and is still pretty small. I'm trying to write a wrapper library for the [GLGE](http://www.glge.org) framework.

I really don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: I have never heard of the "infamous `<init>$` error", is this a GWT error or a GLGE error?  Can you post exactly what the error is and at what point you get it?

Comment: The closest I've heard of looks like the stack trace here: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-remote/issues/detail?id=1 and that is caused by trying to generate new `JSO`s at generator time, which shouldn't be allowed. funkybro is right, a stack trace will help in trying to give you suggestions, plus most info on when you get this (such as where in the glge-gwt proj this can be confirmed).

Comment: Ok, I will soon create a minimal sample project that uses glge-gwt. Then it should be more clear where the error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the error was a subsequent error and has hidden the root cause.

The solution is to actually compile this whole thing now and then, although theoretically unnecessary in dev mode. This led to:

```
Errors in 'file:/.../MaterialLayer.java'
       Line 90: missing formal parameter
> function (in) {
> ------------^
```

The corresponding Java code was:

```
public native void setMapinput(int in) /*-{
    this.setMapinput(in);
}-*/;
```

As `in` is a reserved word in JS, this probably led to some subsequent problems. Long story short, I changed the parameter to `input` and got it working...

Frustrating!

Comment: Ouch, nasty indeed.  Goes to show using GWT doesn't mean you don't need to know JS.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert. I avoided this problem by moving my extended JavaScriptObject class outside of my EntryPoint:onModuleLoad() implemention.